# How to fix weird ordering in setProperty or put for Properties class

Tags: java, properties

I'm having a dilemma on the ordering of setProperty or put for the Properties class.

The idea is that I want to save a sorted Properties file. I've got the sorting classes ready, but when I do a *setProperty* or *put*, the arrangement becomes weird.

```
Properties tmp = new Properties();
tmp.setProperty("A1","B");
tmp.setProperty("A2","B");
tmp.setProperty("A3","B");
tmp.setProperty("A4","B");
tmp.setProperty("A5","B");
```

The output when you do a *tmp.list(System.out)* becomes:

```
-- listing properties --
A4=B
A3=B
A2=B
A1=B
A5=B
```

The same arrangement goes when using *put*.

I'm not sure why.. All I need is to save the sorted properties in a *.properties file.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you need to get them sorted?

Comment: If you want to sort properties, then most likely your design is wrong.  Java doesn't care about properties ordering.  If you save properties into a file, the order will be seemingly random, but when you load it back, everything will be loaded and used correctly.  There is no need to sort them for any viable purpose.

Comment: @sp00m This can be useful for debugging - imagine a large unsorted properties list (like the one returned from `System.getProperties()`) where you are looking for `file.encoding`...

Comment: I need to sort them for readability. Its not necessary, but I'd like to be able to read the file (about 50-60 lines) easier for debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Properties` class extends `Hashtable` and thus does not define a guaranteed sort order.  Your best best would be to try a `TreeMap` instead as it gives natural sort order of the keys.    If you want to `save` and `load` though, you'll have to roll your own logic as these operations do not come on `TreeMap`.  Let me know if you want to see code examples for these.

Comment: I'm currently using a TreeMap to sort the original properties file. But I think my best solution for now is to hard write the output into the properties file.. :/

Comment: I think I'll just use TreeMap and hard write the properties file. Thanks!